# Ionic v4 Login page incorrectly extends base class with super injector call undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to use a base class with ionic v4 to add all services I am using all around the app, using the following scripts:

for the base class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseClass {
  constructor(private gateway: GatewayService){
  }
}
```

And in the login page, I used the super injector:

```
export class LoginPage extends BaseClass implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  message: string="";
  constructor(private gateway: GatewayService) { 
      super(gateway);
    }
...
}
```

The 2 problems I am having are:

1. An error on LoginPage class saying:

> Class 'LoginPage' incorrectly extends base class 'BaseClass'.   Types
>   have separate declarations of a private property 'gateway'

2. I can't use this.gateway.call() as it was in previous versions of ionic.

What I tried in the base class, is like the following:

```
constructor(private injectorObj: Injector, private gateway: GatewayService){
    this.gateway = this.injectorObj.get(GatewayService);
}
```

But still having the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Make the **gateway** property **protected**. On both constructors.